# Count function usage

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex

"auto"          { count(); return(AUTO); }

"break"         { count(); return(BREAK); }

"case"          { count(); return(CASE); }

"char"          { count(); return(CHAR); }

what is the role of count() in lex?

Also, the statement "column += 8 - (column % 8);" in the following function is not clear

```
void count()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; yytext[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (yytext[i] == '\n')
            column = 0;
        else if (yytext[i] == '\t')
            column += 8 - (column % 8);
        else
            column++;

    ECHO;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: column += 8 - (column % 8);   What is the use of this statement? This can be written as column += 8;

Comment: @Venkatesan: only if column%8 is 0. That's clear just looking at what you wrote. The expression moves column to the next multiple of 8.

Answer (score 1):

That is just a function someone wrote; it has nothing to do with flex. And it may not be a good model of how to write lexical analyzers, so I would recommend not using it as a guide.

The function is trying to maintain the current column position, taking tab stops into account. So when it hits a tab, it moves the column number to the next tab stop, assuming they are every eight characters.

Obviously, the complication is pointless in the case of these patterns, since they cannot contain newlines or tabs. `column += yyleng;` would suffice for such a pattern. I suppose whoever wrote that wasn't worrying about optimisation, which is fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

OP clarified the question, pointing to this statement:

```
column += 8 - (column % 8);
```

It is not, as OP assumed, the same as

```
column += 8;
```

This is a form often found for tab-expansion, e.g., setting tab-stops at columns 0,8,16,24 (if counting from zero, and if the tab interval is 8).  The point in subtracting `(column % 8)` from `8` and adding *that* to *column* is that the difference is the distance to the next tab-stop.  So,

- if *column* is in the range `[0 .. 7]`, it will be mapped to `8`,
- if *column* is in the range `[8 .. 15]`, it will be mapped to `16`,
- and so forth

At each point, *column* is the offset from the left margin (where newline goes to).  The function `count()` assumes that there are no other nonprinting characters than `\n` (newline) and `\t` (tab).